# Are 3 hours enough layover time for transferring from EZE to AEP?

Tags: airport-transfer, airports, argentina, eze, aep

I'm looking into flying to Argentina with an international flight from Rome to Buenos Aires (EZE), then have a domestic flight from the AEP airport to Ushuaia.

Is 3 hours enough time for this connection or its too risky (flight delays, time it takes to leave the EZE airport - baggage claim, passport controls.., transfer time to AEP, traffic, ..)?

Comment: asking if it's 'enough' is going to be subjective (see [help]).  WHether it's possible is another story - it's certainly possible, however, whether it's worth risking it is up to you, and will depend on the airline as well. Some are 'riskier' than others. Aerolineas Argentinas, for example, is notorious for delays (at least it was when I was there 3 years ago).